# Does all 4 services Speech to Text (STT), Natural Language Classifier (NLC), Conversation, and Text to Speech (TTS) are required for project-into?

Tags: project-intu

I am new to BluemixIBM and project-INTU.

Does all 4 services **Speech to Text (STT), Natural Language Classifier (NLC), Conversation, and Text to Speech (TTS)** are required for **project-into**?

I have only create one service "**Conversation**" and added its credentials into **Intu Gateway**.

There is a client - **Intu Gateway**. When I am trying to establish a connection using it. It is not connecting and saying that "connecting to parent" and nothing more. Don't have any idea about it.

Comment: The connection issues will be fixed in a fixpack. Here's the related GitHub issue: https://github.com/watson-intu/self-sdk/issues/4

Answer (score 2):

For the expected usage of Project Intu you will want all those services (STT/NLC/TTS/Conversation). If you are an advanced user you could leave some of those services out. But in the general case you need them.

As of this last week we working to make connections to parents more stable. We should be sending out an stability update later this week. Keep tuned.